# trying to remove login url from header / change evaluation order of layout updates

Tags: layout, magento, header, evaluation

I want to remove the login url from the header, but magento won't budge. In the local.xml file I have the following code:

```
<reference name="top.links">
  <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
</reference>
```

After a little debugging I found that the login url is added AFTER it is "removed" (customer.xml:75 of the base/default theme.

How can I change the order in which layout updates are processed? Surely the local.xml is supposed to override just about anything?

edit:
Just to be clear, I am building a theme, so editing existing files is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd think that, but it [gets tricky](http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/8893108762/order-of-block-creation-in-layout-updates).  You didn't mention it in your post, but what handle tag are you putting your reference tag in?  The base `custoemr.xml` file that adds the `customer/getLoginUrl` is run from the `customer_logged_out` handle.  Even if your code's in `local.xml`, if it's in a `default` handles or full action name handle, it will run after the code in `catalog.xml` because `local.xml` only wins on a **per handle**.

If that didn't make sense, just add this to your `local.xml` and you should be good to go.

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
      <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
    </reference>    
</customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: I put it in the default handle. I cannot BELIEVE I didn't try this. Thank you!